# Local subdomains for a standalone application

Tags: go, proxy, dns, reverse-proxy

I have a website, which is composed by three smaller 'independent' subsites:

- mysite

  - index.html
  - favicons
  - images
  - doc

    - index.html
    - css
    - img
    - js
    - ...
  - editor

    - index.html
    - images
    - js
    - src
    - ...

Where `doc` is a site created with [Hugo :: A fast and modern static website engine](https://gohugo.io/), `editor` is the [mxgraph Graphditor example](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/index.html); and the remaining files make a hand-made landing page.

Besides deploying to any web server, I'd like to distribute the site as an 'standalone application'. To allow so, I wrote this really simple server in go:

```
package main

import (
  flag "github.com/ogier/pflag"
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
  "net/http/httputil"
  "os"
  "path/filepath"
)

var port = flag.IntP("port", "p", 80, "port to serve at")
var dir = flag.StringP("dir", "d", "./", "dir to serve from")
var verb = flag.BoolP("verbose", "v", false, "")

func init() {
  flag.Parse();
}

type justFilesFilesystem struct {
  fs http.FileSystem;
}
type neuteredReaddirFile struct {
  http.File
}

func (fs justFilesFilesystem) Open(name string) (http.File, error) {
  f, err := fs.fs.Open(name)
  if err != nil { return nil, err; }
  return neuteredReaddirFile{f}, nil
}

func (f neuteredReaddirFile) Readdir(count int) ([]os.FileInfo, error) {
  return nil, nil;
}

func loggingHandler(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        requestDump, err := httputil.DumpRequest(r, true)
        if err != nil { fmt.Println(err); }
        fmt.Println(string(requestDump))
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func main() {
  str, err := filepath.Abs(*dir)
  if err != nil { os.Exit(1); }
  fmt.Printf("Serving at port %d from dir %s\n\n",*port,str)

  http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d",*port), loggingHandler(http.FileServer(justFilesFilesystem{http.Dir(*dir)})))
}
```

As a result, I can run `simpleserver -d <path-to-mysite>` and browse the sites through `localhost`, `localhost/doc` and `localhost/editor`.

Then, I'd like to use custom (sub)domain(s) such as `mylocal.app`, `doc.mylocal.app` and `editor.mylocal.app`. So, I added the following line to my the `/etc/hosts` file: `127.0.0.1   mylocal.app`. Therefore, I can browse `mylocal.app`, `mylocal.app/editor` and `mylocal.app/doc`. Moreover, I was able to change it to `mylocal.app`, `mylocal.app:<editor-port>` and `mylocal.app:<doc-port>` with different packages.

However, when I try to use a subdomain, it is not properly resolved, so any reverse-proxy strategy won't work. Since wildcards are not supported, I can add additional entries in the `/etc/hosts` file, but I'd prefer to avoid it.

Although, an alternative solution is to run [dnsmasq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq), I'd like to keep the application standalone. I found some equivalent golang packages. However, I feel that many features are supported which I don't really need.

Furthermore, since I don't really have to resolve any IP, but to provide an alias of `localhost`, I think that a proxy could suffice. This would also be easier to configure, since the user could configure the browser only, and no system-wide modification would be required.

Yet, all the traffic from the user would be 'filtered' by my app. Is this correct? If so, can you point me to any reference to implement it in the most clean way. I know this is quite subjective, but I mean a relatively short (say 10 lines of code) snippet so that users can easily check what is going on.

**EDIT**

I'd like to use something like:

```
func main() {
    mymux := http.NewServeMux()
    mymux.HandleFunc("*.mylocal.app", myHandler)
    mymux.HandleFunc("*", <systemDefaultHandler>)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mymux)
}
```

or

```
func main() {
    mymux := http.NewServeMux()
    mymux.HandleFunc("editor.mylocal.app", editorHandler)
    mymux.HandleFunc("doc.mylocal.app", docHandler)
    mymux.HandleFunc("*.mylocal.app", rootHandler)
    mymux.HandleFunc("*", <systemDefaultHandler>)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mymux)
}
```

These are only snippets. A complete example is [this](https://gist.github.com/ahmdrz/c0f18f69e7409fcc47a73c78d41d5f64), which was referenced in the comments by @Steve101.

However, at now, I don't know what *systemDefaultHandler* is. And that is not solved there.

Apart from that, @faraz suggested using [goproxy](https://github.com/elazarl/goproxy). I think that the `HTTP/HTTPS transparent proxy` is the default handler I am looking for. But, using a package only to do that seems excessive to me. Can I achieve the same functionality with built-in resources?

Comment: Does this one suit your requirements? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42730590/local-subdomains-for-a-standalone-application

Comment: I think that you mistakenly pasted a link to this same thread. At least, that's what I am seeing.

Comment: Apologies - https://gist.github.com/ahmdrz/c0f18f69e7409fcc47a73c78d41d5f64

Comment: Thanks for your interest. However, that's a different part of the problem. Given that all the requests are redirected to my app, I use what is explained there to decide which content to serve. The problem I am facing now is how to make those requests reach my app, so that it can decide.
In the link you provided they talk about an online service. Therefore, although it is not explitcitly explained, they must be using any other piece of software, such as nginx.
Thank you again for your interest.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there's no dead simple way to do this through Go. You'll need to intercept your system's DNS requests just like dnsmasq, and that's inevitably going to require some modification the system DNS config (`/etc/resolv.conf` in Linux, `/etc/resolver` on a Mac, or firewall rule) to route your DNS requests to your app. Going the DNS has the downside that you'd need to build a DNS server inside your app similar to [pow.cx](http://pow.cx/docs/dns_server.html), which seems unnecessarily complicated.

Since mucking with system config is inevitable, I'd vote for making changes to the hosts file on boot or when a directory is added/removed (via [fsnotify](https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify).) On shutdown, you can clear the added entries too.

If you're looking to isolate these changes to a specific browser instead of make a system-wide change, you could always run your application through a proxy server like [goproxy](https://github.com/elazarl/goproxy) and tell your browser to use that proxy for requests. For example, you can do this in Chrome through its preferences or by setting the `--proxy-server` flag:

```
--proxy-server=<scheme>=<uri>[:<port>][;...] | <uri>[:<port>] | "direct://"
```

See [Chrome's network settings docs](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings) for more details.

Also, if you're willing to much with browser configs, you could just use [an extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/virtual-hosts/aiehidpclglccialeifedhajckcpedom?hl=en) to handle the requests as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there no way to intercept those requests by setting some configuration in the browser instead of system-wide?

Apart from that, I suppose `fsnotify` is useful if I plan to add/remove/modify the path of any of the subsite/subdomains. It is not required If the same three are maintained, is it? That's my best option right now. But I'd prefer to ask the user to set up the browser, instead of prompting for admin privileges to modify a file.

Comment: You only need fsnotify if you want directory changes to update the available domains in real-time. Also, I've updated my answer about the browser-specific use case.

Comment: Thanks. I also edited my first message to improve it, after checking these references you provided. I find using a browser extension interesting. However, I'd like to focus on what part of goproxy I need, and whether it'd be possible to achieve the same functionality with buil-in resources. In the end, I don't need a full-featured proxy. I searched for other alternatives, such as [llb](https://github.com/kirillDanshin/llb), but It lacks the 'default behaviour' that I need.

Answer (score 0):

there is only solution that would work without proxy is that you register an domain for this and make an offical dns entry with wildcard to 127.0.0.1 like *.myApp.suche.org. So any client that resolve the ip get 127.0.0.1 and work local. this way you do not need administrator rights to modify the /etc/hosts or equivalent.
If it should work behind proxy without modify the resolver (etc/hosts etc) you can provide an wpad.dat (Javascript for Proxy detection) that say for your domain all traffic goes you server and the rest to the real proxy. If this is served in you server the script can automaticaly contain the real proxy as default.